# Short circuit in Peavey Valve King VK212

Tags: amplifier, short-circuit, tube

This is a follow up question from:
[Guitar amplifier repair: burnt fuse, capacitor, what else?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/522602/guitar-amplifier-repair-burnt-fuse-capacitor-what-else/)

I continue to work on the same case. In another module I've found a short to ground where the red dot is:
[image]

What I did so far:

1. Removed and checked C212, C210, C213, C211, C216 -> caps seem fine, short still in there with all of them gone.
2. Checked D208 -> is fine.
3. If any of the power tubes is removed -> no short.
4. As soon as all are in -> short in the red dot point.

Can the tubes be causing this short? How to test it? Optically they look fine.

I have to add that before assembling I have switched the amp on and the tubes all seemed to glow normally. It was simply complete silence on the output.

Comment: How are you determining that you have a short there?  That is apparently the filament supply, so I would exepect the resistance to ground to be fairly low.  If you are assuming that a beep from the continuity check on a DVM indicates a short circuit, you should be aware that the continuity check will sound for some low resistance, not necessarily a near-zero resistance.  One of my DVMs will indicate continuity for 40 Ohms or less - the resistance of the power tube filaments could eaily be less than that.  The 6L6 power tube filaments are about 7 Ohms, which would show continuity on most DVMs.

Comment: After hint from JRE below that this is the heater power supply I got this feeling of chasing a ghost. I did use a continuity tester and you are of course right...

But I have measured the resistance of filament of all the tubes and they all are 0.7 - 0.9 Ohms (6L6GCMSTR tubes from Ruby). Can it really be so low?

Comment: The 6L6 filament draws 0.9 amp at 6.3 volts, which means its resistance is 7 Ohms at operating temperature.  The resistance will be much less when cold, so your measurements are not unreasonable.  If the tubes alll light normally, the filaments should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

Remove power tubes one by one until the short goes away. Replace the one that causes the short to go away.  Repeat after replacing the dead tube as there could be more than one bad tube.

Alternatively, pull all the tubes out and measure the filament resistance. Look for values that are out of the ordinary - for a 12V tube, the resistance should be around 40 to 50 ohms.  Any value extremely higher (or open) is bad, any that looks like a short circuit is bad.

The point you are looking at connects to a flag marked "HTR" via R213.  "HTR" is probably the heater supply for the tubes.  If a tube goes bad, then the heater filament could short to ground and cause your problems.